Count opened tickets
I have to count opened tickets between a period. My table has this structure



idissue
creation
statusChangedDate
Status




100
2024/06/01
2024/06/29
Closed


200
2024/06/10
2024/06/29
Opened


200
2024/06/01
2024/06/30
prepared


200
2024/06/10
2024/03/07
Closed


300
2024/08/01
2024/08/01
Opened


300
2024/08/01
2024/09/03
prepared



I've tryed to solve from different ways but I can't achieve it
First
VAR _Month = SELECTEDVALUE(DimCalendarIssues[Month])
VAR _Year = SELECTEDVALUE(DimCalendarIssues[Year])
VAR _FinMes = EOMONTH(DATE(_Year, _Month, 1), 0)

RETURN
    CALCULATE(
        DISTINCTCOUNT(Fac_Jira[IdIssue]),
        FILTER(
            Fac_Jira,
            Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate] >= DATE(2024,06,01)
            && Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate] <= _FinMes 
            && NOT(Fac_Jira[IdStatus] IN {[Closed], [Finished], [Cancelled]})
            && Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate] = 
                CALCULATE(
                    MAX(Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate]),
                    Fac_Jira,
                    Fac_Jira[IdIssue] = EARLIER(Fac_Jira[IdIssue])
                    && Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate] >= DATE(2024,06,01)
                    && Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate] <= _FinMes 
                )
            )
    )

second using intermediate table
VAR _Month = SELECTEDVALUE(DimCalendarIssues[Month])
VAR _Year = SELECTEDVALUE(DimCalendarIssues[Year])
VAR _FinMes = EOMONTH(DATE(_Year, _Month, 1), 0)

VAR _lastStates = 
    SUMMARIZE(
        FILTER(
            Fac_Jira,
            Fac_Jira[CreationDate] > DATE(2024, 06, 01)
        ),
        Fac_Jira[IdIssue],
        "LastDateState", MAX(Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate]),
        "LastState", 
            CALCULATE(
                MAX(Fac_Jira[IdStatus]),
                FILTER(
                    Fac_Jira,
                    Fac_Jira[IdIssue] = EARLIER(Fac_Jira[IdIssue]) &&
                    Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate] = MAX(Fac_Jira[StatusCreatedDate])
                )
            )
    )
VAR _Filtered =
    FILTER(
        _lastStates,
        [LastDateState] <= _FinMes &&
        NOT([LastDateState] IN {[Opened], [Finished], [Cancelled]})
    )

RETURN
    COUNTROWS(_Filtered)

Neither works well.
I appreciate your help.

Based on your approches,why not try the below approach to count the opened ticket in a specific date range.
CountOpenedTickets = 
VAR StartDate = DATE(2024, 6, 1)
VAR EndDate = EOMONTH(StartDate, 0)   

RETURN
CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Fac_Jira[IdIssue]),
    FILTER(
        Fac_Jira,
        Fac_Jira[CreationDate] <= EndDate &&  // Ticket must be created before or on EndDate
        Fac_Jira[StatusChangedDate] > StartDate &&  // Ticket must still be opened after StartDate
        Fac_Jira[Status] IN {"Opened", "prepared"}  // Only count tickets that are opened
    )
)


A more straightforward approach is to use Power Query to expand your tickets table.
Preferably, the table should be expanded in Power Query (Data ingestion) instead of the data modelling layer (DAX) due to model performance.
Expanding the table has the benefit of using the Storage Engine, instead of the formula engine, making your calculation faster.
More info here:
https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/formula-engine-and-storage-engine-in-dax/
Assuming FactJira look like this:



idissue
creation
statusChangedDate
Status




100
01/06/2024
29/06/2024
Closed


200
10/06/2024
29/06/2024
Opened


200
01/06/2024
30/06/2024
prepared


200
10/02/2024
07/03/2024
Closed


300
01/08/2024
01/08/2024
Opened


300
01/08/2024
03/09/2024
prepared



I modified row 4, the creation column was greater than the column statusChangedDate
Steps

Create an expanded version of the tickets table with the assistance of a  custom Power Query function (below).

Power Query: Table FactJiraExpanded
let
    Source = FactJira,
    #"Invoked Custom Function" = Table.AddColumn(Source, "ExpandDates", each ExpandDates([creation], [statusChangedDate])),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Invoked Custom Function",{"creation", "statusChangedDate"}),
    #"Expanded ExpandDates" = Table.ExpandListColumn(#"Removed Columns", "ExpandDates"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Expanded ExpandDates",{{"ExpandDates", type date}})
    in #"Changed Type"

PowerQuery: Function ExpandDates
(StartDate as date, EndDate as date) =>

let 
DateList= {Number.From(StartDate)..Number.From(EndDate)},
TransformList = List.Transform(DateList,each Date.From(_))

in TransformList


Create a DAX Calendar Table

Calendar =
ADDCOLUMNS (
    CALENDAR (
        MIN ( FactJiraExpanded[ExpandDates] ),
        MAX ( FactJiraExpanded[ExpandDates] )
    ),
    "Month", MONTH ( [Date] ),
    "MonthYear", FORMAT ( [Date], "mmm-yy" ),
    "MontYearIndex", FORMAT ( [Date], "yyyymm" ),
    "Year", YEAR ( [Date] )
)


Create your DAX measure to count the different statuses:

Number of Tickets = DISTINCTCOUNT(FactJiraExpanded[idissue])

Output

